# constant like PHP_EOL for tabulation php

Tags: php, tabs, eol

Please help,
how can i find the constant like PHP_EOL for tabulation
My code wrote file which has a lot of generated tabulations and new lines
new lines wrote correctly, but i have a lot of "\t\t"
see example:

```
common.app \t/loader \t/growl \t\t/error \t/form
```

Comment: There isn't a predefined tabulation constant; but you can always define your own if you feel that it is necessary

Comment: I define it in the code in string type
But it wrote incorrectly as in example

Comment: At first I failed to see how a bunch of `char(9)` calls were better than `\t` in your code, until I realized that it was the output file that contained the literal `\t`. So with that in mind there has to be something wrong with the code that generates this text, so please edit your answer and post the PHP code as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok I found solution

`chr(9)` wrote tabulation to output file

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

PHP_EOL is a Constant from Core PHP. You could simply define your own Constants and use them. For example:

```
<?php

    defined("TAB1") or define("TAB1", "\t");
    defined("TAB2") or define("TAB2", "\t\t");
    defined("TAB3") or define("TAB3", "\t\t\t");
    defined("TAB4") or define("TAB4", "\t\t\t\t");
    defined("TAB5") or define("TAB5", "\t\t\t\t\t");


    $string = "common.app"     . TAB1 . "/loader" . TAB1 . "/growl" . 
               TAB2 . "/error" . TAB1 . "/form";
```

Answer (score -6):

I solved using css

```
<style>
.MyCSS{
    border:1px solid #FFF; 
    width:10em; 
    float:left; 
    font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>
<?php 
// here the selection query
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
<div>
<div class="MyCSS">
<?php stripslashes($row['Country']);?>
</div>
<?php echo stripslashes($row['CountryDescription'])."<br>";?> 
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: tabulation with php using css

Comment: And this needs results from a database? Shouldn't it work without?